# ¿Cómo darle tamaño a imágenes en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

¿Cómo puedo hacer que las imágenes permanezcan en su tamaño original? Es que cuando las agrego se hacen pequeñas para mantener la pantalla.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Planos Fisicos'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 141, 44, 158),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: (() {
            if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          }),
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //Scrollbar(child: ListView.builder(itemCount: 5, itemBuilder: (c, i) => MyItem,),),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('imagenes/planof1.jpg'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('imagenes/planof2.jpg'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('imagenes/planof3.jpg'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset('imagenes/planof4.jpg'),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              'Aqui podemos apreciar algunos planos que he realizado a mano con todas las herramientas necesarias',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.purple,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                letterSpacing: 2,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Ese el código que llevo al momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si mantienes el tamaño original de la imagen, no cabrá en la pantalla probablemente. Lo mejor que quedes hacer es usar un `ListView` o un `PageView` y hacer que cada imagen ocupe el 100 % del ancho y el alto. Puedes usar `MediaQuery.of(context)` o `LayoutBuilder` para obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla.

Comment: Gracias, utilicé el ListView y se ve mucho mejor, ahora solo tengo un detalle con un botón que no me deja ir hacia otra página

Comment: Haz una nueva pregunta entonces con esa duda. Por otro lado, podrías autocontestar esta pregunta añadiendo el código con la modificación

Comment: Me llama la atención que usas Column en lugar de un ListView, creo que es lo correcto como comenta Manuel.

Answer (score 0):

asset tiene en su codigo para redimensionar la imagen.

`Image.asset('imagenes/planof4.jpg', width: 200,height: 250)`

Espero te ayude mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable en este caso es usar un **[`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)** en lugar de `Column`, esto para asegurar que las imágenes conserven el tamaño, cambia a usar un **[`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)**:

```
...
...
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        Image.asset('imagenes/planof1.jpg'),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        Image.asset('imagenes/planof2.jpg'),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        Image.asset('imagenes/planof3.jpg'),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        Image.asset('imagenes/planof4.jpg'),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        ),
        Text(
          'Aqui podemos apreciar algunos planos que he realizado a mano con todas las herramientas necesarias',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            color: Colors.purple,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            letterSpacing: 2,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
...
...
```